# Gridsearch in randomforest (RandomForestSRC)

Tags: r, random-forest, grid-search

I am using RandomForestSRC to create a random forest model using regression, and I want to perform a gridsearch on the optimal mtry, nodesize, ntrees, nodedepth in combination in order to better visualize the optimization process.

I have tried the following:

```
mtry <- c(4,8,16)
nodesize <- c(50,150,300)
ntrees <- c(500,1000,2000)
nodedepth <- c(5,10)

frmodel <- rfsrc(mort_30 ~ variable1+variable2+variable3, #(ect)
data= data.train, mtry= mtry, nodesize= nodesize, ntrees=ntrees,
nodedepth=nodedepth, blocksize=1, importance=TRUE, seed=40)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
I if (mtry < 1 | mtry >n.xvar) mtry <- max(1, min(mtry, n.xvar)):
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

It seems I wont be able to assign more than one value to these. Is there another way to do this, short of manually making a tree for every single combination?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tune](https://rdrr.io/cran/randomForestSRC/man/tune.rfsrc.html) for search for mtry and nodesize, then maybe just run this for different `ntrees` , for example:

```
nodesize <- c(5,10,20)

model <- tune(Ozone ~ .,data = airquality,
mtryStart = 2,
nodesizeTry= nodesize, ntreeTry=100,
blocksize=1, importance=TRUE, seed=40)

model$results
   nodesize mtry       err
1         5    1 0.5750139
2         5    2 0.4420183
3         5    3 0.3750303
4         5    4 0.3781430
5         5    5 0.3255283
6        10    1 0.6128187
7        10    2 0.4719501
8        10    3 0.3825911
9        10    4 0.3771207
10       10    5 0.3523660
11       20    1 0.6981993
12       20    2 0.5251094
13       20    3 0.4451690
14       20    4 0.4305362
15       20    5 0.4099460
```